# Artificial intelligence for strategy games like solarmax

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

What would be the best approach to create the AI for a Real Time Strategy game? any books or tutorials that you like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start, especially since you mention Solarmax, would be the [Google/University of Waterloo AI challenge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_AI_Challenge) from a while back called [Planet Wars](http://ai-contest.com/).
And most useful of all, you can find the analysis of the game from the guy who won the challenge [here](http://quotenil.com/Planet-Wars-Post-Mortem.html).
And another one [here](http://iouri-khramtsov.blogspot.com/2010/11/google-ai-challenge-planet-wars-entry.html).

Comment: Thks! that's exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

There is a good book by Peter Norvig on artificial intelligence: http://norvig.com/paip.html

And you can even take part in a free course by this author at Stanford on artificial intelligence in the next few months:
http://www.ai-class.com/

This might teach you the *best* approach to create a real AI system. However, maybe you want something simpler for a game.